# paste0 not printing the message inside else statement

Tags: r

I don't get any error but I was expecting that when I type an integer that is not 1,2,3,4 the code should enter in `else` statement and print what is in `paste0` function. What is wrong?

```
escolha <- as.integer(readline(prompt="Enter your choice: "))

if(escolha == 1){
  print("Cool you choose addition!")
} else if (escolha == 2) {
  print("Cool, you choose subtraction!")
} else if (escolha == 3) {
  print("Cool, you choose multiplication!")
} else if (escolha == 4){
  print("Cool, you choose division!")
} else{
  paste0("It's not possible to use ", escolha," as input.")
  escolha<- as.integer(readline(prompt="Choose a valid number (1 a 4): "))
}

num1 <- as.double(readline(prompt="What is the first number? "))

num2 <- as.double(readline(prompt="What is the second number? "))

resultado <- switch (escolha, (num1+num2), (num1-num2), (num1*num2), (num1/num2))

cat("The result is: ", resultado)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`paste0()` (and `paste()`) assemble a string and return it. You still need to print the result to the screen with `print()` or `cat()`, like this:

```
cat(paste0("It's not possible to use ", escolha," as input.\n"))
```

(added the `\n` at the end, so the `readline()` prompt that follows will be on a separate line)